# How to calculate the difference in cents between a note and an arbitrary frequency?

Tags: theory, frequency

Let's say I have the note A 440Hz and the frequency 450Hz. How do I calculate the distance in [cents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_%28music%29) between that note and that frequency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## *c* = 1200 × log<sub>2</sub>(*f*<sub>1</sub>/*f*<sub>0</sub>)

The frequency *f* of a note *n* semitones away from A4 is ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note#Note_frequency_.28hertz.29)):

> *f* = 2<sup>*n*/12</sup> × 440 Hz

More generally, to calculate one frequency from another based on their distance in semitones:

> *f*<sub>1</sub> = 2<sup>*n*/12</sup> × *f*<sub>0</sub>

To answer your question, solve for *n* to get semitones:

> *n* = 12 × log<sub>2</sub>(*f*<sub>1</sub>/*f*<sub>0</sub>)

And multiply by 100 for cents:

> *c* = 1200 × log<sub>2</sub>(*f*<sub>1</sub>/*f*<sub>0</sub>)

Given your example, the distance in cents between 440 Hz and 450 Hz:

> *c* = 1200 × log<sub>2</sub>(440/450)
> *c* = –38.9

so 440 Hz is about 39 cents below 450 Hz.

For more information, see the [mathematics of musical scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_musical_scales). There’s also some information about the logarithmic scale in the linked entry for [musical cents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_%28music%29#Use).

Answer (score 3):

The first formula shown on you wiki link is the one you want:

From wiki:

""If one knows the frequencies a and b of two notes, the number of cents measuring the interval from a to b may be calculated by the following formula (similar to the definition of decibel):

[image]

Likewise, if one knows a note a and the number n of cents in the interval from a to b, then b may be calculated by:

[image]

E.G. for your given two frequencies, 440Hz and 450Hz

3986*log(450/440)= 38.9 cents

and in the other direction:

3986*log(440/450)= -38.9 cents

And checking our answer with the second formula:

440*2^(38.9/1200) = 450.0 Hz

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_%28music%29

Comment: +1 for putting it in functions you can actually find on a calculator. However it might be worth pointing out that log2(b/a) = log10(b/a)/log10(2) = ln(b/a)/ln(2). Thus the correct value of the constant 3986 is 1200/log10(2)=3986.31371 etc. The fundamental maths is easier to remember than a mysterious constant.